# How to derive $\imath q^\mu\mathcal{M}_ \mu(k;q;p)=0$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, ward-identity, self-energy

\begin{equation}
\imath q^\mu\mathcal{M}_ \mu(k;q;p)=-\imath\tilde{e}\mathcal{M}_0(p;k-q)+\imath\tilde{e}\mathcal{M}_0(p+q;k)
\end{equation}
This is exactly the Ward-Takahashi identity for two external fermions.
In the case of full-vertex function this equation can be written as
\begin{align}
q^\mu\Gamma_\mu(p,q,p+q)=S_F^{'-1}(p+q)- S_F^{'-1}(p)   
\end{align}
Taking the limit $q_\mu\to 0$ yields the Ward identity

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial S_F^{'-1}}{\partial p^\mu}=\Gamma_\mu(p,0,p)
\end{equation}
My question is how to derive
\begin{equation}
\imath q^\mu\mathcal{M}_ \mu(k;q;p)=0\end{equation}(Which is used in Regularization and Renormalization of vacuum polarization diagrams) starting from the general Ward-Takahashi identity  $
\imath q^\mu\mathcal{M}_ \mu(k;q;p)=-\imath\tilde{e}\mathcal{M}_0(p;k-q)+\imath\tilde{e}\mathcal{M}_0(p+q;k)
$?

Answer (score 1):

The Ward-Takahashi identity is a statement about correlation functions, whereas the Ward identity is a statement about S-matrix elements. Diagrammatically, we can write the Ward-Takahashi identity as
[image]

In each diagram on the left, the momentum entering the electron line is $p$ and the momentum exiting is $q$. We can make use of the LSZ reduction formula to extract from each diagram a contribution to an S-matrix element by taking the coefficient of the product of poles
$$\left(\frac{i}{q_{\mu}\gamma^\mu-m}\right)\left(\frac{i}{p_{\mu}\gamma^\mu-m}\right)$$
The terms on the right side of the diagrammatic picture each contain one of these poles, but neither contains both poles. Thus, the right hand side doesn't contribute to the S-matrix. Hence, in the special case that $\mathcal{M}$ is an S-matrix element, we get the usual Ward identity.

Comment: Can you derive it explicitly, I mean starting from Ward Takahashi identity and ends in Ward identity...@arow257

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you find unsatisfactory here. I started with the Ward-Takahashi identity in its most general form, explicitly showed the right-hand side was zero using the LSZ reduction formula, and hence concluded that the Ward identity holds.

Comment: "The terms on the right side of the diagrammatic picture each contain one of these poles, but neither contains both poles. Thus, the right-hand side doesn't contribute to the S-matrix.," I don't understand how this  "neither contains both " make zero contribution..@ arow257

Comment: The right-hand side looks like $$a\left(\frac{i}{(q-k)_\mu\gamma^\mu-m}\right)\left(\frac{i}{p_\mu\gamma^\mu-m}\right)+b\left(\frac{i}{q_\mu\gamma^\mu-m}\right)\left(\frac{i}{(p+k)_\mu\gamma^\mu-m}\right)$$, which we will get from the propagators on the external electron lines. From the LSZ reduction formula, we know the corresponding S-matrix element is given by the coefficient of $\left(\frac{i}{q_\mu\gamma^\mu-m}\right)\left(\frac{i}{p_\mu\gamma^\mu-m}\right)$, but said coefficient is zero. Hence, the right-hand side does not contribute to the S-matrix element.

Comment: The precise form of $a$ and $b$ depends on the photon lines you have attached, but it won't have the poles that you require to have a nonzero contribution to the S-matrix.

Comment: Ok I understand 75 percentage of your statements, I don't have much knowledge about LSZ reduction formulae, can you state the things without using this term...@arow257

Comment: It's rather hard to avoid invoking LSZ because the LSZ reduction formula tells you how to get between correlation functions and S-matrix elements. The Ward-Takahashi identity is a statement about correlation functions and the Ward identity is a statement about S-matrix elements, so it's kinda necessary to use LSZ to get between them. However, LSZ is really just a fancy way of saying that to get an S-matrix element, you take the correlator, remove the propagators from the external legs, and put the external momenta on-shell

Comment: Just the subtlety here is that the incoming momentum is $p$ and the outgoing one is $q$, so those are the ones you want the coefficient of.